# Сборка APK файла из исходников

Tags: java, android, linux, android-studio, apk

Можно ли из исходников Android Studio проекта, собрать APK файл( вне студии ) через терминал(Linux)?

Comment: "...и если да, то как?" ведь?

Comment: Конечно можно, там же ведь Gradle проект. Можно выполнить команду в консоли ./gradlew начнется закачка всякого, а потом ./gradlew и название таска для сборки apk

Comment: @D-side Вы правы

Comment: вряд ли вас интересует буквальный ответ на ваш вопрос. переформулируйте, пожалуйста, текст вопроса (нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса) так, чтобы на него можно было дать полноценный ответ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Да, можно. [Gradle](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradle) вам в помощь

1. Устанавливаем *gradle*
2. Пишем файл `build.gradle` - к счастью это [довольно просто](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/theory/gradle.php)
3. С консоли запускаем gradle (считая что в текущем каталоге валяется файл `build.gradle`
4. Профит